# Como obtener label por post con php?

Tags: php, post, entrada

¿hay forma de recibir el valor de un label u otro elemento que esté al lado de un input  por php? Tengo el siguiente código.

```
<div class="formulario__category__plates">
  <?php $platos = mysqli_query($conexion, $pCombinations);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($platos)) { ?>
   <label class="formulario__plate__name"><?php echo $row ['name_plate'];?></label>
   <p class="formulario__plate__price"><?php echo number_format($row ['price_plate'], 2);?></p>
   **<input type="text" class="formulario__plate__input" value="0" name="combinations[]">**
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row ['price_plate'];?>">
 <?php } mysqli_free_result($platos);?>
</div>
```

Estoy mandando unos inputs como array por post(lo que está con negrita). Y ya sé como recibirlos, pero también deseo obtener el nombre y el precio del input donde se haya escrito algun valor. Pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es algo asi: https://fs22.formsite.com/shogunparties/form1/index.html en la parte donde se pone la cantidad de platos. Gracias.

Comment: puedes mandarlos medianrte querystring con $_GET o mediante ajax con $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todos los campos tendrán el mismo índice, entonces solo necesitas hacer un foreach para acceder a campos y valores, pero te conviene agregar ID de cada registro, no el precio:

```
<div class="formulario__category__plates">
<?php
    $platos = mysqli_query($conexion, $pCombinations);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($platos)) { ?>
<label class="formulario__plate__name"><?php echo $row ['name_plate'];?></label>
<p class="formulario__plate__price"><?php echo number_format($row ['price_plate'], 2);?></p>
<input type="text" class="formulario__plate__input" value="0" name="combinations[]">
<input type="hidden" name="id_plate[]" value="<?php echo $row ['id_plate'];?>">
<?php } mysqli_free_result($platos);?>
</div>
```

Procesando el formulario:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['id_plate'] as $i => $id_plate) {
    if($_POST['combinations'][$i] > 0) {
        // Aquí debes verificar que existe el producto
        // y también obtener el precio adecuado
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM platos WHERE id_plate = $id_plate");
        // Antes de la siguiente línea conviene revisar si
        // realmente existe el producto, creo que es con mysqli_num_rows()
        $plato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        // Ya puedes tomar el precio de $plato['price_plate']
    }
}
```

Este código es solo un ejemplo para que puedas acceder al campo combinations y asociarlo con la id del producto, ademas de no permitir que el usuario modifique cosas como el precio, pero, **IMPORTANTE** debes evitar el riesgo de inyección SQL validando lo que recibes por formulario.

Comment: muchas gracias!! Ya pude hacerlo, con el código en el php al recibir, lo del precio que estaba ahi es para otra cosa(hacer un calculo antes de enviar). Pero lo del input con el id oculto sirvió. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás hayan mejores formas de hacerlo, lo primero que se me ha ocurrido es:

```
<div class="formulario__category__plates">
  <?php 
  $platos = mysqli_query($conexion, $pCombinations);
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($platos)) {  
  ?>
  <label class="formulario__plate__name"><?php echo $row ['name_plate'];?></label>
  <p class="formulario__plate__price"><?php echo number_format($row ['price_plate'], 2);?></p>
 **<input type="text" class="formulario__plate__input" value="0" name="combinations[]">**
   <input type="hidden" name="nombre_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row ['name_plate'];?>">0
   <input type="hidden" name="precio_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row ['price_plate'];?>">
 <?php          
     $i++;
   } mysqli_free_result($platos);?>
   <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $i?>">
</div>
```

le pones un contador $i, y el los names de los input hidden, se lo añades al final `name="nombre_$i"` y `name="precio_$i"`. Tambien le añades un input hidden con el contador total. 
Luego en el php lo recoges con un for.

```
$total = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'total') // que viene siendo $_GET['total'];
$array_con_todo = new Array();
for($i=0;$i<=$total;$i++){
  $array_con_todo[$i]['nombre'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre_'.$i);
  $array_con_todo[$i]['precio'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'precio_'.$i);
}
```

y como tienes el total del inputs, pues recorres uno a unos y los vas guardando.

Esta es la primera manera que se me ha ocurrido viendo tu codigo. Seguramente haya algo mas efectivo

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, eso estaría bien, pero es para recibir todos los nombres y precios, como mencioné deseo recibir el label de los input "donde se haya escrito algun valor".